# Xcode icon issue

Tags: xcode

In the Application Loader I always get an error than icon specified in the Info.plist file is not under the top level app wrapper.

Please help i have been solving this problem for 2 days but it is not yet solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well what's the path to your file then? It must not be Bla/Icon.png but Icon.png (not in a subfolder)

Comment: The file is in desktop and i have also copied it to the project

Comment: what is the file path in the bundle. the error is that icons cant be in a subfolder of the app